# Why can we observe thin-film interference or optical fringes when a film is illuminated by broadband radiation?

Tags: optics, waves, interference

To observe [thin-film interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film_interference) (optical fringes), the time that a beam of radiation spends in the film should be less than the coherence time of the beam so the emerging waves can interfere with one another. The coherence time of "monochromatic" radiation is defined by the actual spectral bandwidth or wavelength range of the radiation (e.g., [[ref](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Epogosyan/teaching/PHYS_130/FALL_2010/lectures/lect33/lecture33.html)]), and so it is possible to determine over what film thicknesses this phenomenon is relevant provided we know the wavelength of radiation and refractive index of the medium.

However, we are able to observe [thin-film interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film_interference#Broadband_source) with broadband radiation as well, even though it is incoherent. Why is that? How can we predict the range of film thicknesses over beyond which interferences can no longer be observed?

Answer (score 2):

When a spectrally narrow source is used, we see that the reflection or transmission intensity is modulated as a function of the ratio of the local film thickness to the wavelength of the used light.

You can imagine broadband illumination as many narrowband sources impinging at the same time. Each color forms an interference pattern, but because the wavelengths are different the maxima and minima appear at different spots. This creates rainbow-like effects as in soap bubbles.

Answer (score 2):

It is the pigments in the light-sensitive cells in your eye that determine the band width and the coherence time. Those are acting like band filters.

You would not see much in a black-and-white photo of interference fringes when illuminated with white light.